# HBase: One region server have all the requests Per Second

Tags: hbase

I have an High Availability (HA) HBase running on AWS EMR. A HA HBase means that I have 3 master nodes instead of one. I also have 61 regions servers
Using the HBase UI, I am seeing one of my regions servers have around ~1000 requests per seconds and the rest of the region servers have around ~60 requests per seconds on the table.

What does this mismatch mean? How can I fix the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual sign of 'hotstpotting' -- that your tables are not split in a way that enables all region servers to be involved in serving them.

You need to think about access patterns of your application and compare them with the reality of how your tables are actually split and how you designed your row keys.

For the easiest way to dig into this, I would suggest the following:

1. In HBase UI, note the region server that is getting all the hits
2. Clock on the link for that region server (its name is clickable)
3. This will open the UI for that specific region server. Scroll down and you will see all regions from all tables that this region server is serving. You will also see the actual 'beginning' and 'end' of each region server

This information should help you determine what's wrong: is this region server serving too many tables? Or too many busy regions? How come other servers aren't assigned any of these regions? Maybe you designed your row keys in such a way that causes the hotspotting (the usual most likely problem)

If that's not it, then one thing I noticed is that even if you design your tables for equal splitting (like via using the hex splitter for instance) you may still end up with the situation where too many busy regions from the SAME busy table are assigned to just one server. In this case HBase has a handy property that enforces even region distribution across different servers at a table level.